# Match selected formatting from html to plain text

Tags: regex, email, parsing, mailgun

I'm using Mailgun's awesome [Inbound Routing](http://www.mailgun.com/inbound-routing) to parse my incoming emails, remove the HTML and email signatures, which leaves me with the raw body of text.

Below is a small example of what is returned:

```
{
  "stripped-html": "<html><body><div style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px;\">Testing with <b>bold<\/b>&#160;and <u>stuff<\/u><br><\/div><div style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px;\"><u><br><\/u><\/div><div style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 13px;\">:)<\/div>&#13;\n                <div><div><br><\/div><div>--&#160;<\/div><div>Tim Smith<\/div><div><br><\/div><\/div>&#13;\n                 &#13;\n                <p style=\"color: #A0A0A8;\"><\/p>&#13;\n                <div>&#13;\n                    <br><\/div><\/body><\/html>",
  "stripped-text": "Testing with bold and stuff\n\n:)",
  "stripped-signature": "-- \nTim Smith"
}
```

What I want to do is take the plain `stripped-text` but also replicate basic formatting like bold, italic, and underlined. In this example the word "bold" is **bold** and the world "stuff" is underlined.

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Comment: You'd be better off parsing the HTML than the stripped text, because the stripped text has no information about what should or could be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the "stripped-html" string and sanitize it, this way you get rid of the escape strings...

...then you could do two things:

1. Run a regular expression that matches the styling and disregard all other content.    althought the latter two are deprecated since HTML4 and are replaced by  for bold and a css style property (font-style: italic). 
   For example: 
   First you match outer html with`(<\w* \w*=".*?">)(.*)(<\/\w*>)` 
   then recursively look for bold and other elements such as `<b>(.*?)</b>` for b tags with no  further attributes.

Once replaced all b tags with bold then you could simply move on to the next tag.

2. Use a parser - for example http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ could be a good start if you want to use PHP.

Comment: If you're downvoting me could you please tell me why that is, this way I can edit it and make it better? Thank you!